# if statement facing error in percentage C++ code

Tags: c++, if-statement, percentage

I have faced the problem the formula of percentage doesn't work properly

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int tmarks,intermarks, passmarks;

    float per;

    cout << "Enter Your Inter Marks:\n";
    cin >> intermarks;
    cout << "Enter Your Total Marks:\n";
    cin >> tmarks;
    cout << "Enter Your PassMarks:\n";
    cin >> passmarks;
    per = (intermarks/tmarks) * 100;
    cout << "percentage:" << per;

    if (per >= 45 && passmarks >= 50) {
        cout << "Welcome To Uni\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Improve Your Marks You are eligible\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: try this way: `per = ( float(intermarks) / float(tmarks) ) * 100.0;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Also, you really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 1):

If `intermarks = 50` and `tmarks = 75`, then `intermarks/tmarks` will be `0`. Since both are integers. You need to typecast before division operation. This way `float(intermarks) / float(tmarks)` will be `0.67` and `per` will be `67`